# Yii:: redirect www.domain.com/index.php to www.domain.com without using htaccess

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I have a requirement where I need to redirect

```
domain.com/index.php, www.domain.com/index.php & www.domain.com/index/ to www.domain.com
```

My application is not using .htaccess file. It has to be done with php only.

Comment: What have u tried did u try some code in yii ??

Comment: I tried exploding the url and if there is "index" removing it. But, seems not feasible. This will be my last option if I will not find any solution :(

Comment: Try reading this link u may getsome solution 

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Answer (score 4):

I guess no solution without .htaccess file , so build one

Set main.php in your yii configuration, at component :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
     'caseSensitive'=>false,        
),
```

## LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

to be

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

then go to .htaccess file, and try to modify to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

if above does not work try with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

move .htaccess file to root directory, where is index.php resides.

www
 - protected
 - index.php
 - .htaccess

Restart your server and then all things will work